# C++: How to tell eclipse which version of library to use

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, boost

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and it has a version of boost (1.46.1)

installed to **/usr/lib** and include files in **/usr/include**.

I have compiled my own version (1.51.1) locally and have been using it fine up until now.

I am working on a new project which is using many includes in `/usr/include` and libs in `/usr/lib` so in my include path I have `/usr/include` and `/home/aly/libs/boost/stage/include`,

similarly in lib search paths I have `/usr/lib` and `/home/aly/libs/boost/stage/lib`. However when I add boost libraries to link it seems to be grabbing them from `/usr/lib` and it causing my code not to work.

If I remove `/home/aly/libs/boost/stage/lib` and `/home/aly/libs/boost/stage/include`

it works fine but now can't use the 1.51 features.

Is there an easy way around this problem?

Comment: Change the order of the paths in the project settings?

Comment: Tried this, not sure how it actually searches though

Comment: did you tried #define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_51" ? Not sure if it works

Comment: @georgesl where should I put this define?